# How to use password for ftp user and still maintain pem authentication for root?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, authentication

I have got a machine (ubuntu 20.04.2) with root access and root authentication is done strictly with pem file. There is need to setup `vsftpd` & `ftp` user which has been done. But `ftp` user cannot login to machine apparently because `PasswordAuthentication` is set to `NO` in SSH config file.

```
filezilla error: no supported authentication methods
```

Is there a way to maintain status quo for root authentication using PEM file only *and still* have `ftp` user strictly authenticated using password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the following two options in your `sshd` config file:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

This allows the use of passwords for your FTP user (and all other users).

```
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
```

This explicitly allows `root` to only login via `ssh` using a keyfile, and prevents logging in as `root` with password.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Very helpful...